# Why do I need an in-modifier in a generic to make it accept super classes?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am working with some code that utilises generics, and I have a hard time trying to understand why a certain code work.

I have made a short example wherein the "error" can be replicated:

```
sealed class Sealed {

    class Klass : Sealed()
}

class Generic<T>

fun main(){
    val map = mutableMapOf<String,Generic<Sealed.Klass>>()
    map.put("hello", Generic<Sealed>())
}
```

as you can see, my mutableMap takes another generic. in the put-method, I pass in the superclass of Klass into the Generic class.

This doesn't work, and I think for obvious reasons: Klass is an specific implementation of Sealed, so the map only wants that.

So, to actually get to accept Sealed a generic parameter, I can modify the map's generic type to "in":

> ```
> val map = mutableMapOf<String,Generic<in Sealed.Klass>>()
> ```

I'm pretty sure I get what in does (it only lets the class accept T as an input parameter), but I do not understand why it makes this example work, since I am not specifically using T as an input/output

Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifically using `T` as an input/output, but the API of `Map` does.  Because `Map<Generic<Sealed.Klass>>.get()` returns `Generic<Sealed.Klass>?`, adding a `Generic<Sealed>` to the collection could cause `get` to return something with an unacceptable type.  Using `in` projection will prevent you from using methods on `Map` which could cause this problem, which makes the code safe to compile.

Comment: thank you for your answer! What could an unnacceptable type be?

Let's say I add a function to Generic: 
`fun returnInput(input:T):T {return input}`. 

Now, defining Generic as `class Generic<in T>` would cause an error with `returnInput()`, but defining the map as `val map = mutableMapOf<String,Generic<in Sealed.Klass>>()`

would not throw an error... So what exactly is the in good for? 

Also apologies, Im still trying to understand these concepts :)

Comment: A `Generic<Sealed.Klass>` can theoretically return Klass instances from its functions and properties, although you didn't define any functions or properties for Generic so it's an incomplete example. If the compiler let you put a `Generic<Sealed>` into your Map whose value type is `Generic<Sealed.Klass>` then when you retrieved it, it would incorrectly be returned as a `Generic<Sealed.Klass>` and would choke when you tried to request a `Sealed.Klass` from it and it returned a `Sealed`. By restricting it to `in`, you are safely prevented from requesting return values from items from the map.